# flask url_for() adding a "/" before the url while pointing to static folder

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have this folder structure for my flask app:

```
app.py
 /templates
     login.html
     index.html
 /static
   /css
     main.css
     login.css
   /js
     login.js
   /images
     image.png
```

When I use `<link rel="stylesheet" href={{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}>` inside login.html, it renders as
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">` (Note the prepended slash before static).

Now, this leads to 404 errors because I intend to run to run this application with /app1/ in the NGINX server block. Due to the prepended slash, the application tries to find main.css in `XXX.XXX.XX.XX/static/css/main.css` rather than `XXX.XXX.XX.XX/app1/static/css/main.css`

If I do not use url_for() and write the entire file path inside login.html i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css">` (without prepending the slash before static), it works just fine.

But I want to use url_for() inside the templates, as it is considered a good practice and saves a lot of trouble.

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

[EDIT]: The existing questions ask about "adding a prefix" to url_for(). This question pertains to understanding why url_for() is prepending "/" in its route, and how to remove the prepended slash.The application is working if I write the entire url path in the template, but that is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If saving the file is creating some trouble why not CDN the bootstrap by providing the link

I hope that helps

Comment: Even if I use CDN for bootstrap, I'll still need to link local images, css, and js files.